# How to find CNF and DNF for the formula?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How to find noncanonical CNF and DNF for the formula $$p\Leftrightarrow(q\Leftrightarrow r)? $$
I know how to find canonical CNF and DNF, but how can I get noncanonical from that?

Comment: $p\iff q$ is equivalent to $(p\wedge q)\vee (\neg p \wedge \neg q)$. Every expression using only $\neg,\wedge,\vee$ can be transformed to CNF/DNF using only distributive property, de Morgan and reducing double negations. Can you specify what do you mean by noncannonical form?

Comment: typo @Przemek. $p\wedge q$

Comment: What do you mean by 'non-canonical'?

Comment: @math_ I second the previous questions, what would non-canonical mean in this context?